# Transaction declined in magento 1.9 when testing with DPS PxPay2.0

Tags: magento, transactions

I am getting transaction declined errors (The transaction was Declined (BH)) when using a test with DPS Payment Express account (PxPay 2.0) for processing credit cards on a website.I am using test credit card no 4111111111111111, expiry date is any future date ,any name for card holder name and 3 digit csv numer.

I am getting following error(response)

Response:DECLINED
Response Code:BH
Currency:USD
Amount: 2016.92
Card:411111........11
Card Holder:MANISH KUMAR
Card Type:Visa
Date:20141007
Time:060747
Transaction Type:Purchase
Help Text:The transaction was Declined (BH)

Can any one please help me....

Answer (score 2):

It is solved by change the currency to NZD.

Answer (score 0):

For others that are using PXPOST "The transaction was Declined (BH)" means that the port is not configured for the Currency you are trying to charge in.

In our case we already had a multi-currency merchant account with our bank but we had to call Payment Express and ask them to enable the new currency we were sending.